# I need help to fix a minor issue

Tags: javascript

Basically I want the word problem to present this, Johnny has 1 nickel(s), 4 dime(s) and 3 quarter(s). How much money does Johnny have? (answer: $1.20)
But every time I change it my code it doesn't work.

This is the code that I wrote and need help to change the word problem.

```
<script>
 var person1, person2;

 function getPeople() {
     var people = ['Kritarth', 'Sharujan', 'Anveer', 'Krishna', 'Husnain', 'Iser', 'Ishan', 'Harman', 'Hemant', 'Harjot'];

     person1 = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
     person2 = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];

     while (person1 === person2) {
         person2 = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
     }
 }

 function getrandomnumber(min, max, notin) {
     return min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random());
 }

 function getoption(s, ch, num) {
     var a = s.split(ch);
     return a[num - 1];
 }

 var marymoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");
 var johnmoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");
 var maryitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");
 var johnitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");
 var marystuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));

 var johnstuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));

 while (marystuff === johnstuff) {
     johnstuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));
 }
 getPeople();
 var totalleft = marymoney + johnmoney - maryitem - johnitem;
 var str = person1 + " has $" + marymoney + " and " + person2 + " had $" + johnmoney + ". " + person1 + " buys a " + marystuff + " for $" + maryitem + " and " + person2 + " buys a " + johnstuff + " for $" + johnitem + ". They have $" + totalleft + ".";

 document.write(str);
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by inputs? Are you getting from a form. If yes how are you calling your above function

Comment: Also remove the extra script tag at the end of your code you posted

Comment: You need to have a jquery on function which would be called everytime an event happens in your case changes as what you said

Comment: No, the segments of code you provided which are outside a function only run once, when the page is loaded. You either need to use jQuery, any other js framework, or develop your own way to call the scripts defining mary and john's money and item every time you change the input.

Comment: Misa, it is great that you are trying to write code, and you have progressed wonderfully. However, your skills needs serious improvements. I suggest going through MDN references, jQuery docs and/or w3schools tutorials. I am also willing to help you finish your code, since everyone here on stack exchange are so harsh to quickly downvote a beginner programmer's question.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft You should see 'her' history before you jump to conclusions that people aren't willing to help. It's simply that helping [certain individuals](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) becomes exhausting when they fail to do their part in sustaining the community.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft thank you very much for understanding my situation because as you can see i am a beginner in coding and that is why i posted my wuestion on SO so i can get feedback or simple hints on ways to improve because i have a passion for coding. Furthermore, timolawl you are being very rude because you only know one side of the story and i do not know by what you mean when you say 'exhausting'. As a whole if you don't have anything nice to say then please don't say it. I have spent a lot of time simply trying to write the code above and i want to not give up and finish what i started.

Comment: I am working on your code to improve it, come over to https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=QRnCqExlhl

I hope you can learn improvements, like you coding is my passion! Also, please post an answer to your comment here after you learned the solution so it could help future visitors.

Comment: @MisaChan since I didn't see you there, I finished the code.
Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/7cdj72gg/ hope you like it. Comment if you need any more help. Have a great day!

Comment: Update: I went ahead and made this one too: https://jsfiddle.net/7cdj72gg/1/ Have a look and tell me what you think ;)

Comment: Wowwww thank you very very much @DRSDDavidSoft That has helped me immensely, by giving me a different point of view on how to tackle coding word problems! I really appreciate your help, thanks again  and i will now post the answer so others can take a look as well :D

Answer (score 1):

// Define a list of people and items
      var people = ['Kritarth', 'Sharujan', 'Anveer', 'Krishna', 'Husnain',    'Iser', 'Ishan', 'Harman', 'Hemant', 'Harjot'];
     var items  = ['notebook', 'pencil', 'ruler', 'pen', 'eraser', 'binder', 'backpack'];
      var costs  = [20.00,      8.00,     11.00,   15.00, 5.00,     35.00,    100.00  ];

// Get unique and random names
     function getList(list, amount) {
      var index = 0, selected = [];

```
 while (amount-- > 0) {
         index = getRandom(0, list.length - 1);
     selected.push (list[index]);

     // Remove the selected member from the list
     list = list.slice(0, index).concat(list.slice(index + 1));
 }

 return selected;
```

}

// Return an integer between min and max
     function getRandom(min, max) {
     return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
 }

// Show the results
 function showResults () {
   var population = 2;

var everyone = getList(people, population);
      var everything = getList(items, population);

```
 var person = [];
```

// Set each person's name, item and money
       for (var i = 0; i < population ; i++) {
       person[i] = {
           name: everyone[i],
           item: everything[i],
           cost: costs[ items.indexOf(everything[i]) ],
           money: getRandom(50, 100)
       }
   }

var totalleft = person[1].money + person[0].money - person[1].cost - person[0].cost;

```
  var str = person[1].name + " has $" + person[1].money + " and " +     person[0].name + " had $" + person[0].money + ". " +
         person[1].name + " buys a " + person[1].item + " for $" +  person[1].cost + " and " + person[0].name + " buys a " + person[0].item + " for $" + person[0].cost + ". " +
         "They have $" + totalleft + " left.";
```

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
  }

// Originally coded by Misa Chan, improved by David.Refoua.me
  showResults ();